# Как определить запустилось ли приложение?

Tags: c#

Запускаю приложение со своей программы ( `Process.Start("appl.exe");`), так получилось, что приложение может грузиться долго (вплоть до минуты). Как можно определить, когда приложение еще грузиться, а когда уже начало работать?

Comment: Пусть само приложение сообщает об этом. С точки зрения операционной системы, процесс бежит — значит, работает.

Comment: @Виктор Матюхин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Виктор Матюхин, Вы хоть бы ОС указали, да и характер работы приложения можно было бы описать.

Если дело происходит в Линуксе и известно, что "заработавшее" приложение открывает какие-то файлы или сокеты, то можно, например, посмотреть  `/proc/PID/fdinfo/` на предмет дескрипторов, отличных от 0,1,2.

Вообще, почитайте `man proc`. В этом каталаге можно найти много информации о текущем состоянии процесса (и всей системы).

Comment: @avp, раcширение **"appl"** --- **'.exe'**
 
    (хотя, судя по метке, речь идет о винде).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать послать найти главное окно процесса (если окна нет, то приложение скорее всего ещё не стартовало или уже завершилось) и послать ему [сообщение с таймаутом](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Например, .NET-овское свойство `Process.Responding` использует код

```
responding = (NativeMethods.SendMessageTimeout(
           hWnd, 
           0, // msg
           IntPtr.Zero, // wparam
           IntPtr.Zero, // lparam
           2, // flags = SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG
           5000, // timeout in ms
           out dummy) != (IntPtr)0);
```

Но это, конечно, не слишком надёжный способ.

---

Поскольку речь идёт о C#, можно просто воспользоваться кодом

```
process.MainWindowHandle != IntPrt.Zero && process.Responding
```

Answer (score 4):

Если определять необходимо извне, то можно, например, задействовать реестр, файловую систему( создать файл флага ) и т.д и т.п. Затем ежесекундно, например, проверять, установило ли приложение **"appl.exe"** тот самый флаг в единицу( да и вообще, во что угодно ).

Если приложение appl вам не принадлежит( у вас нет исходных кодов ), то, увы, кроме  дизассемблера тут вряд ли что-то может помочь.

С другой стороны, мы не осведомлены о том, что скрывается за названием "appl". Ведь у приложения может быть собственный интерфейс для взаимодействия извне.

Comment: Поллинг? Зачем так сложно? Просто [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) можно взвести.

Comment: @VladD, да тут как кому угодно..

Comment: Да, приложение стороннее, собственного интерфейса для взаимодействия практически уверен что нет.

Понятно,одно что просто сделать не получится.
Спасибо, за советы.